# fcitx doesn't show the candidate box of chinese characters in fluxbox

Tags: debian, fluxbox, fcitx

I have no idea about this. The first time it happened was that I installed wine. But now if I `rm -r .fluxbox/` It returns; 
 However I need all my configuration files, so I simply `cp old-fluxbox/xxx .fluxbox/` It's gone!  
I only copied the `keys`, `menu` and `startup`. 
I am really really confused. 
Digression: I switched to KDE, but after adding a wetget to the panel the desktop crashed. : )

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's somethings really interesting.
by exclusion, the cause is one line in `.fluxbox/startup`

```
compton -b
```

Delete it.
But I still remember I like the shadow of every window including the candidate box.
I mean, there's no conflict before.